# unable add record in table in open office database

Tags: sql

i am getting error `table not found` when i am trying to insert a record in open officebase table 1(please check the image)

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Simply replace `select` with `values`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not syntactically correct, you have to use either `values` or `select` statement :

```
insert into table1(col1, col2, . . . )
     select '8', . . . ;
```

You can also use `values` :

```
 insert into table1(col1, col2, . . . )
      values ('8', . . .);
```

Comment: neither 'values' nor 'select' are working(just see the image)